# primefaces dialog is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is my dialog.

```
<p:dialog closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false"
            header="Confirmation" widgetVar="groupconfirmation">
            <center>
                Do you want to remove this Pin Priority group?<br /> <br />
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" oncomplete="groupconfirmation.hide()"
                    actionListener="#{pinProrityHandler.deletePinPriorityGroup}"
                    update="pinprioritygroup" />

                <p:commandButton value="No"
                    actionListener="#{platformGroupHandler.onGroupReset}"
                    oncomplete="groupconfirmation.hide()" update="pinprioritygroup" />
            </center>
</p:dialog>
```

And this is my java code:

```
  try {                 
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("groupconfirmation.show()");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error {}", e);
    }
```

I don't know why my code is not working.

I am new to primeface.

Comment: Define 'not working' and what did you debug? With a recent PF version, I'm sure there are client-side errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get primefaces widgetVar in javascript and update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609536/get-primefaces-widgetvar-in-javascript-and-update-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Primefaces <= 3.x**

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("groupconfirmation.show();");
```

**For Primefaces >= 4.x**

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("PF('groupconfirmation').show();")
```

Comment: For many of these basic questions there are already existing duplicates in stackoverflow. Many of them with more context detail and mote. It is good practice to find them and mark the questions such. Keeps SO 'clean'